# Angular js binding does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "js/script.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app>
<div>
{{Hello World!}}
</div>

<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
if(typeof angular == 'undefined' )
{
alert("not working");
}
else
{
alert("good");
}
```

I get alerted good, although the page still has

```
{{Hello World!}}
```

What am I missing here? I thought the binding was supposed to work by itself.
I am using angular js 1.2.16 btw

//extra characters because stackoverflow wouldn't let me post the question. Says too much code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All included scripts are good. However you are not telling angular where to start bootstraping your angular application.

You are missing `ng-app` directive on the html tag.

```
<html ng-app>
```

Also the Hello World should be a string.

```
{{"Hello World!"}}
```

Comment: Aah! It has to be a string. Totally missed that. Thanks! :). Btw I have given ng-app directive on body. so it's supposed to be working even with that. IMO It's not necessary to give it on html tag always. Thanks anyways. :)

Answer (score 0):

Working example :

**script.js**

```
var testApp = angular.module('MyTestApp', []);
```

**index.html page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyTestApp">
<head>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be angular.module("LoginApp",[]); ?

Comment: This still doesn't work. Anything inside {{}} has to be a string. That was the error. What you did wasn't really necessary. Anyways thanks.